# How to fix error W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in my sources.list file?

Tags: apt

I have Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial Xerus and when I want to run `sudo apt-get update` or `sudo apt-get autoclean` or `sudo apt-get install (package name)` or `sudo apt-get install -f`, I get the following messages:

```
Citire liste de pachete... 0%
Citire liste de pachete... Terminat
Se construiește arborele de dependență       
Se citesc informațiile de stare... Terminat
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list:5
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list:5
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list:5
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-ro_RO) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list:5
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-ro) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list:5
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list:5
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list:5
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list:5
W: Target Packages (restricted/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list:5
W: Target Packages (restricted/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list:5
W: Target Packages (restricted/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list:5
W: Target Translations (restricted/i18n/Translation-ro_RO) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list:5
W: Target Translations (restricted/i18n/Translation-ro) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list:5
W: Target Translations (restricted/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list:5
W: Target DEP-11 (restricted/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list:5
W: Target DEP-11-icons (restricted/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list:5
W: Target Packages (universe/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list:5
W: Target Packages (universe/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list:5
W: Target Packages (universe/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list:5
W: Target Translations (universe/i18n/Translation-ro_RO) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list:5
W: Target Translations (universe/i18n/Translation-ro) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list:5
W: Target Translations (universe/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list:5
W: Target DEP-11 (universe/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list:5
W: Target DEP-11-icons (universe/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list:5
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:8
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:8
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:8
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-ro_RO) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:8
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-ro) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:8
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:8
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:8
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:8
W: Target Packages (restricted/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:8
W: Target Packages (restricted/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:8
W: Target Packages (restricted/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:8
W: Target Translations (restricted/i18n/Translation-ro_RO) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:8
W: Target Translations (restricted/i18n/Translation-ro) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:8
W: Target Translations (restricted/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:8
W: Target DEP-11 (restricted/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:8
W: Target DEP-11-icons (restricted/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:8
W: Target Packages (universe/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:8
W: Target Packages (universe/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:8
W: Target Packages (universe/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:8
W: Target Translations (universe/i18n/Translation-ro_RO) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:8
W: Target Translations (universe/i18n/Translation-ro) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:8
W: Target Translations (universe/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:8
W: Target DEP-11 (universe/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:8
W: Target DEP-11-icons (universe/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:8
```

And this is my `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

[image: /etc/apt/sources.list]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please consider providing text outputs instead of screenshots. It helps finding the question and improves formatting. Thanks

Answer (score 89, accepted):

`main`, `universe`, `multiverse`, `restricted` are different components of the `Sections` portion in a `sources.list` entry and can not be duplicated for a given entry (same `Type` (e.g. `deb`), `URI` (e.g. `http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/`) , `Suite` (e.g. `xenial`)).

In your `/etc/apt/sources.list`, you have duplicate components (`main`, `restricted`, `universe`) in lines 2 and 5:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted universe multiverse
```

As line 5 is a superset of line 2, you can remove line 2 using your favorite editor or use `sed`:

```
sudo sed -i '2d' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Or comment out the 2nd line:

```
sudo sed -i '2 s/^/# /' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Comment: It's works for me in same issue on installing signal messenger under ubuntu 16.04LTS

Answer (score 41):

***BEWARE:** that this will delete all your repos and you might not be able to install packages with apt anymore until you add a new sources.list file.*

[Reset your repositories](https://askubuntu.com/a/192388/110324) like this

1. `sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list`
2. `sudo software-properties-gtk`
3. Pick your options
4. Save

Comment: Will this remove ppa's?

Comment: @MarkCarpenterJr Yes, if it is in that file. No, if it is a separate file in the directory `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` . A more thorough version of my answer would be to delete the files in the directory `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`

Comment: Be aware that this will delete all your repos and you might not be able to install packages with `apt` anymore until you add a new sources.list file

Answer (score 9):

I have this problem too,I fix it through the error message:

```
"W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple 
times in /etc/apt/sources.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list:5".
```

you can `sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list`.

then locate the second line, use # comment out the line.

save the file, and `sudo apt-get update`,the problem will be solved.

Answer (score 4):

This is issue with Ubuntu 16.04

You can fix it with `xenial-backports`

```
sudo apt install appstream/xenial-backports

sudo appstreamcli refresh --force
```

After the second command you will get

```
AppStream cache update completed successfully.
```

Comment: Not working for me on 16.04.