# An error occurred - Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: synaptic

I always have a red circle in the upper part of my Ubuntu 16.04 screen, and whenever I click it, it says the following:

[image: Error Message]

I can tell that Mono is a cause of this problem; I tried to uninstall it but it didn't seem to work! I can't even reach synaptic!

[image: Can't reach Synaptic]

Comment: Run `sudo apt update`on a Terminal to see in detail what the true problem is. There you should be able to spot the errors listed at the end of the process.

Comment: Also relevant: http://askubuntu.com/questions/760746/how-to-fix-error-w-target-packages-main-binary-amd64-packages-is-configured-m

Comment: @eridani Can I edit my question and show you the output of the command `sudo apt update` ?

Comment: By all means, the most relevant information you provide, the faster we find a solution. Also, remember to try what edwinksl suggested.

Comment: Yeah, I used the links he provided. What I finally did was replace my Sources List with a new generated one (using https://repogen.simplylinux.ch/generate.php) . No more red circle! Thank you all very much for your help :)