# warnings in sudo apt-get update in xenial xerus

Tags: apt, 16.04, package-management, updates

I am very new to Linux and to any stuff related to programming. I tried sudo apt-get update in Xenial xerus but several warnings appear as shown below. I have read some answers

- [How can I automatically fix W: Target Packages ... is configured multiple times?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760896/how-can-i-automatically-fix-w-target-packages-is-configured-multiple-times)
- [How to fix error W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in my sources.list file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760746/how-to-fix-error-w-target-packages-main-binary-amd64-packages-is-configured-m)

for questions similar to mine and tried to apply them but the problem persists.

```
    Hit:1 http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian xenial InRelease
    Hit:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security InRelease             
    Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/atareao/atareao/ubuntu xenial InRelease         
    Ign:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise InRelease                 
    Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial InRelease
    Hit:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-updates InRelease
    Hit:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-backports InRelease
    Hit:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise Release
    Reading package lists... Done 
    W: Target Sources (universe/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:14 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:14
    W: Target Sources (main/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:14 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:14
    W: Target Sources (multiverse/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:14 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:14
    W: Target Sources (restricted/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:14 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:14
    W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:13 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:13
    W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:13 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:13
    W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:13 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:13
    W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_PH) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:13 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:13
    W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:13 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:13
    W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:13 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:13
    W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:13 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:13
    W: Target Packages (universe/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:13 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:13
    W: Target Packages (universe/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:13 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:13
    W: Target Packages (universe/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:13 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:13
    W: Target Translations (universe/i18n/Translation-en_PH) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:13 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:13
    W: Target Translations (universe/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:13 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:13
    W: Target DEP-11 (universe/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:13 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:13
    W: Target DEP-11-icons (universe/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:13 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:13
    W: Target Packages (restricted/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:13 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:13
    W: Target Packages (restricted/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:13 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:13
    W: Target Packages (restricted/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:13 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:13
    W: Target Translations (restricted/i18n/Translation-en_PH) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:13 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:13
    W: Target Translations (restricted/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:13 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:13
    W: Target DEP-11 (restricted/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:13 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:13
    W: Target DEP-11-icons (restricted/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:13 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:13
    W: Target Packages (multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:13 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:13
    W: Target Packages (multiverse/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:13 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:13
    W: Target Packages (multiverse/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:13 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:13
    W: Target Translations (multiverse/i18n/Translation-en_PH) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:13 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:13
    W: Target Translations (multiverse/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:13 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:13
    W: Target DEP-11 (multiverse/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:13 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:13
    W: Target DEP-11-icons (multiverse/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:13 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:13
    W: Target Packages (universe/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:16 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:16
    W: Target Packages (universe/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:16 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:16
    W: Target Packages (universe/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:16 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:16
    W: Target Translations (universe/i18n/Translation-en_PH) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:16 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:16
    W: Target Translations (universe/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:16 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:16
    W: Target DEP-11 (universe/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:16 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:16
    W: Target DEP-11-icons (universe/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:16 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:16
    W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:16 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:16
    W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:16 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:16
    W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:16 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:16
    W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_PH) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:16 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:16
    W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:16 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:16
    W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:16 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:16
    W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:16 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:16
    W: Target Packages (multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:16 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:16
    W: Target Packages (multiverse/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:16 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:16
    W: Target Packages (multiverse/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:16 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:16
    W: Target Translations (multiverse/i18n/Translation-en_PH) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:16 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:16
    W: Target Translations (multiverse/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:16 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:16
    W: Target DEP-11 (multiverse/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:16 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:16
    W: Target DEP-11-icons (multiverse/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:16 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:16
    W: Target Packages (restricted/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:16 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:16
    W: Target Packages (restricted/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:16 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:16
    W: Target Packages (restricted/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:16 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:16
    W: Target Translations (restricted/i18n/Translation-en_PH) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:16 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:16
    W: Target Translations (restricted/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:16 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:16
    W: Target DEP-11 (restricted/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:16 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:16
    W: Target DEP-11-icons (restricted/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:16 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:16
    W: Target Packages (universe/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:17 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d        /official-package-repositories.list:17
    W: Target Packages (universe/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:17 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:17
    W: Target Packages (universe/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:17 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:17
    W: Target Translations (universe/i18n/Translation-en_PH) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:17 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:17
    W: Target Translations (universe/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:17 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:17
    W: Target DEP-11 (universe/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:17 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:17
    W: Target DEP-11-icons (universe/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:17 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:17
    W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:17 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:17
    W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:17 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:17
    W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:17 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:17
    W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_PH) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:17 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:17
    W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:17 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:17
    W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:17 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:17
    W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:17 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:17
    W: Target Packages (multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:17 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:17
    W: Target Packages (multiverse/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:17 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:17
    W: Target Packages (multiverse/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:17 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:17
    W: Target Translations (multiverse/i18n/Translation-en_PH) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:17 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:17
    W: Target Translations (multiverse/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:17 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:17
    W: Target DEP-11 (multiverse/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:17 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:17
    W: Target DEP-11-icons (multiverse/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:17 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:17
    W: Target Packages (restricted/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:17 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:17
    W: Target Packages (restricted/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:17 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:17
    W: Target Packages (restricted/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:17 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:17
    W: Target Translations (restricted/i18n/Translation-en_PH) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:17 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:17
    W: Target Translations (restricted/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:17 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:17
    W: Target DEP-11 (restricted/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:17 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:17
    W: Target DEP-11-icons (restricted/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:17 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:17
    W: Target Packages (universe/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:18 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:18
    W: Target Packages (universe/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:18 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:18
    W: Target Packages (universe/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:18 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:18
    W: Target Translations (universe/i18n/Translation-en_PH) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:18 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:18
    W: Target Translations (universe/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:18 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:18
    W: Target DEP-11 (universe/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:18 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:18
    W: Target DEP-11-icons (universe/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:18 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:18
    W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:18 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:18
    W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:18 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:18
    W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:18 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:18
    W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_PH) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:18 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:18
    W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:18 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:18
    W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:18 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:18
    W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:18 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:18
    W: Target Packages (multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:18 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:18
    W: Target Packages (multiverse/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:18 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:18
    W: Target Packages (multiverse/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:18 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:18
    W: Target Translations (multiverse/i18n/Translation-en_PH) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:18 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:18
    W: Target Translations (multiverse/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:18 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:18
    W: Target DEP-11 (multiverse/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:18 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:18
    W: Target DEP-11-icons (multiverse/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:18 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:18
    W: Target Packages (restricted/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:18 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:18
    W: Target Packages (restricted/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:18 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:18
    W: Target Packages (restricted/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:18 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:18
    W: Target Translations (restricted/i18n/Translation-en_PH) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:18 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:18
    W: Target Translations (restricted/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:18 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:18
    W: Target DEP-11 (restricted/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:18 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:18
    W: Target DEP-11-icons (restricted/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:18 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:18
    W: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/InRelease: Signature by key 630239CC130E1A7FD81A27B140976EAF437D05B5 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
    W: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/InRelease: Signature by key 630239CC130E1A7FD81A27B140976EAF437D05B5 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
    W: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/InRelease: Signature by key 630239CC130E1A7FD81A27B140976EAF437D05B5 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
    W: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/Release.gpg: Signature by key 630239CC130E1A7FD81A27B140976EAF437D05B5 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
    W: Target Sources (universe/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:14 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:14
    W: Target Sources (main/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:14 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:14
    W: Target Sources (multiverse/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:14 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:14
    W: Target Sources (restricted/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:14 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:14
    W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:13 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:13
    W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:13 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:13
    W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:13 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:13
    W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_PH) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:13 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:13
    W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:13 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:13
    W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:13 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:13
    W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:13 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:13
    W: Target Packages (universe/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:13 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:13
    W: Target Packages (universe/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:13 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:13
    W: Target Packages (universe/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:13 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:13
    W: Target Translations (universe/i18n/Translation-en_PH) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:13 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:13
    W: Target Translations (universe/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:13 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:13
    W: Target DEP-11 (universe/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:13 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:13
    W: Target DEP-11-icons (universe/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:13 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:13
    W: Target Packages (restricted/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:13 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:13
    W: Target Packages (restricted/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:13 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:13
    W: Target Packages (restricted/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:13 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:13
    W: Target Translations (restricted/i18n/Translation-en_PH) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:13 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:13
    W: Target Translations (restricted/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:13 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:13
    W: Target DEP-11 (restricted/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:13 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:13
    W: Target DEP-11-icons (restricted/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:13 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:13
    W: Target Packages (multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:13 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:13
```

And here are the contents of `sources.list`:

[image]

Here is the screenshot after running sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list and putting some edits suggested by @Raphael:

[after_pasting_some_lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htvui.png)

Comment: Have you manually messed around in your sources.list? As it looks messed up. It does contain precise sources and disabled xenial sources - which is both wrong for a 16.04/xenial installation.

Comment: My advice: backup your sources.list and then replace it with one generated using this generator: https://repogen.simplylinux.ch/

Comment: From the error messages it looks like the problems are in the file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list - can you please provide the contents of this file?

Comment: @dufte

These were the original contents of the sources.list: 

deb http://ubuntu.ipserverone.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
main
main

main
main
main
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security universe
deb-src http://ubuntu.ipserverone.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
 universe main
 universe main
 universe main
 universe main

Comment: @dufte Sorry, how shall I know which ones to check?

Comment: You can select without issues all boxes in the top 2 categories - aka 'Ubuntu Branches' and 'Ubuntu Updates' - while backports in the last one shouldnt be needed.  Then add the 'Ubuntu Partner Repos' and you are done.

Comment: @dufte 
I tried the "quick method" from this link:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/78951/how-do-i-remove-a-malformed-line-from-my-sources-list

Comment: @darkeale The contents of the sources.list and official-package-repositories.list are exactly the same.

Comment: @lala - you should NOT simply copy a sources.list content from another ubuntu release/version. Precise is a different version and therefor uses other sources.

Answer (score 1):

It is what it says in the warning:

```
configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:13 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:13
```

To remove the warning:

- It seems you have enabled `precise` sources.list in `xenial`.

  **PLEASE RECTIFY THAT IMMEDIATELY**

  AN EXAMPLE `sources.list` OF XENIAL:

> deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted universe multiverse
>
> deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted universe multiverse
>
> deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse
>
> deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse
>
> deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-proposed main restricted universe multiverse
>
> deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
>
> deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse
>
> deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse
>
> deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-proposed main restricted universe multiverse
>
> deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse

- If it is a new installation of Ubuntu and you do not have any ppas or external repositories configured then, type in the following command:

  ```
  sudo rm -rf /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list /var/lib/apt/lists/* && sudo apt-get update
  ```
- If it is not, then:

  - First compare the two files:

    ```
    sdiff /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list
    ```
  - Check if there are any diferrences. If found any will be shown using `>` or `<`.
  - Comment those lines in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list, by opening it in a text editor and then update your repositories, by typing:

    ```
    sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && sudo apt-get update
    ```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44942/discussion-on-answer-by-raphael-warnings-in-sudo-apt-get-update-in-xenial-xerus).

Answer (score 0):

As the contents of /etc/apt/sources.list and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list are the same (according to the comments above), first delete them both:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Then launch software-properties-gtk

```
 sudo software-properties-gtk
```

Then tick the boxes next to the repositories that you want to enable and a new /etc/apt/sources.list will be created with the correct settings.