# Ubuntu 17.04's Software Updater keeps telling me to upgrade

Tags: upgrade, 16.10, 17.04

I did the distro upgrade from 16.10 to 17.04 and it successfully upgraded and I am at 17.04 now.
But the Software Updater seems to think I am still at 16.10

See attached pictures.

Will it eventually get that I am at 17.04?

I keep clicking Upgrade... about once a week and it wont change anything even if it does it successfully every time.

[image: Software Updater]

[image: Details]

```
uname -r
4.10.0-21-generic

lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.10
Release:    16.10
Codename:   yakkety
```

Comment: Can you append the output of `uname -r` and `'lsb_release -a` to your question, please?

Comment: Will do in about 10 hours

Comment: I guess my distro is just not upgrading. Is there something I can do to force it?

Comment: Seems like yes, and no.  The kernel version is correct for 17.04.  How did you perform the distro upgrade?

Comment: By clicking "Upgrade..." I also did a:'sudo apt-get update' and 'sudo dist-upgrade'

Comment: I would encourage you to remove any third party PPA's, and proprietary graphics drivers, then `sudo do-release-upgrade` so see if this finishes your upgrade.  I really don't know if this will work...

Comment: Thanks. What you say makes sense. I have a nvidia graphic and so far I was unlucky with upgrades (since 14.04) mostly graphic problems and I always end up installing from scratch. When I install from scratch after an unsuccessful upgrade it always works like a charm. I will try your suggestion before installing from scratch.

Comment: I don't have any third party PPA. I did remove the 3 proprietary drivers I had and re-booted. Then I tried sudo do-release-upgrade and it went through the steps and the last step is type "y" to finish upgrade and restart. After the restart, I am at the same result when I "lsb_release -a"

Comment: When I "apt-get update" I get about a hundred lines similar to this: "W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list:58" Can this help figure out my problem?

Comment: [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760746/how-to-fix-error-w-target-packages-main-binary-amd64-packages-is-configured-m) describes a solution to that problem

Comment: Thanks Charles Green. I fixed the "multiple times" problem but I still can't do the release upgrade. Oh well