# Unistall MongoDB and getting "W: Target Packages in command line"

Tags: command-line, 20.04, uninstall, mongodb

When I did sudo apt-get update on the command line I found errors with "W: Target Packages"

```
sudo apt-get update
```

```
Hit:1 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                       
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [109 kB]                       
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]                      
Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [101 kB]                    
Hit:6 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_15.x focal InRelease                                      
Ign:7 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/4.4 InRelease                       
Hit:8 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/4.4 Release                         
Hit:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:10 http://lenovo.archive.canonical.com focal InRelease
Fetched 324 kB in 2s (142 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: Target Packages (multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.4.list:1
W: Target Packages (multiverse/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.4.list:1
W: Target Translations (multiverse/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.4.list:1
W: Target Translations (multiverse/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.4.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (multiverse/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.4.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (multiverse/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.4.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (multiverse/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.4.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons (multiverse/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.4.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (multiverse/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.4.list:1
W: Target CNF (multiverse/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.4.list:1
W: Target CNF (multiverse/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.4.list:1
W: Target Packages (multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.4.list:1
W: Target Packages (multiverse/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.4.list:1
W: Target Translations (multiverse/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.4.list:1
W: Target Translations (multiverse/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.4.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (multiverse/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.4.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (multiverse/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.4.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (multiverse/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.4.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons (multiverse/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.4.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (multiverse/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.4.list:1
W: Target CNF (multiverse/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.4.list:1
W: Target CNF (multiverse/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.4.list:1
```

I have tried

```
 apt-get remove --purge mongodb
```

```
apt-get autoremove --purge mongodb
```

The result

```
~$ sudo apt-get purge mongodb-org*
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'mongodb-org-unstable-tools' for glob 'mongodb-org*'
Note, selecting 'mongodb-org-mongos' for glob 'mongodb-org*'
Note, selecting 'mongodb-org-tools' for glob 'mongodb-org*'
Note, selecting 'mongodb-org-unstable-server' for glob 'mongodb-org*'
Note, selecting 'mongodb-org-unstable-shell' for glob 'mongodb-org*'
Note, selecting 'mongodb-org-shell' for glob 'mongodb-org*'
Note, selecting 'mongodb-org-unstable-mongos' for glob 'mongodb-org*'
Note, selecting 'mongodb-org-unstable' for glob 'mongodb-org*'
Note, selecting 'mongodb-org' for glob 'mongodb-org*'
Note, selecting 'mongodb-org-server' for glob 'mongodb-org*'
Package 'mongodb-org-mongos' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mongodb-org-shell' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mongodb-org-tools' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mongodb-org-unstable' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mongodb-org-unstable-mongos' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mongodb-org-unstable-server' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mongodb-org-unstable-shell' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mongodb-org-unstable-tools' is not installed, so not removed
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libcurl3
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  mongodb-org* mongodb-org-server*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 21 not upgraded.
After this operation, 62.2 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 187143 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing mongodb-org-server (4.0.4) ...
Failed to stop mongod.service: Unit mongod.service not loaded.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mongod, action "stop" failed.
dpkg: error processing package mongodb-org-server (--remove):
 installed mongodb-org-server package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 5
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mongodb-org-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: We can help you better if you [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1316235/edit) to show us the complete output of your remove and autoremove commands. We are not good at guessing. Meanwhile, you really should fix that seemingly unrelated problem with your sources.

Comment: I'm not seeing a `sudo` in there, nor a specific error message from the removal process. What does `sudo apt remove --purge mongodb` result in when you run it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list
```

```
sudo software-properties-gtk
```

- Go to Other Software
- Pick your options
- Save

Answer from
[How to fix error W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in my sources.list file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760746/how-to-fix-error-w-target-packages-main-binary-amd64-packages-is-configured-m)

Comment: Don't delete the source.list, open it with an editor, e.g., `nano +58 /etc/apt/sources.list`. Should put you at least close to the crime scene, it should look the same as the one you have in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.4.list`.

Comment: ....if you remove a source entry, all packages originate from that source will be unmaintained by the *package-system*, i.e., until you restore the origin.