# Sudo apt-update && upgrade issue?

Tags: upgrade, updates

So I am running WSL 2, and acquired the ubuntu 20.04 LTS installation through the windows store.

I have downloaded a few programs like (Python 3 et el). I also know I have to keep my system up to date. Although I have not touched the kernel upgrade stuff. I have been using the commands sudo apt-update and then sudo apt-upgrade.

This was great for the first two to three months until these messages started to appear.

```
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list:2
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list:2
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list:2
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list:2
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list:2
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list:2
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list:2
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list:2
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list:2
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list:2
```

Now can someone explain what is actually going on, why are they configured multiple times? Are these backups? How do I go about tidying the multiple logs up? Is it safe to do so? Little confused here. All feedback grateful and welcome. Thank you in advanced.

Big Edit:

```
shanzem@Shanzem-Laptop:~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list
deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ focal-pgdg main
deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ focal-pgdg main
```

How Bizarre! going to comment out line 2! will post results.

PROBLEM SOLVED

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As explained in other answers like [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760746/how-to-fix-error-w-target-packages-main-binary-amd64-packages-is-configured-m) and [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760896/how-can-i-fix-apt-error-w-target-packages-is-configured-multiple-times), your problem is duplicate sources in one of your sources.list files.

The error states that the problem is with the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list`

The error also states that the duplicate is listed on line 1 and line 2 of the file.

You can use the following command to edit the file:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list
```

Use this text editor mode to remove duplicate lines.

**If line 1 and line 2 are identical**, delete **one** of the two lines and then press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> to save the file and then press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to exit nano.

After you edit the file, run the following commands to update your package list and upgrade (update) your software to the newest versions:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

---

**If the two lines are not identical**, please edit your question and post the contents of your `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list` file so I can provide more detailed instructions.

Comment: Thank you! will do!

Comment: @Shanzem Awesome. If this fixed your problem, please click the checkmark icon to the left of the answer to mark it as the accepted solution. Thanks.

Comment: Solved thank you! :D